# How to convert comma separated negative value to array in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i want to Convert comma separated negative value to array in PL/SQL. It works fine when i pass positive value but fail when any negative value in the list.

Hence my list value should have 100,-150,-200

```
DECLARE

      L_INPUT_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(4000) := :P21_AMOUNT;             
      L_COUNT BINARY_INTEGER;    
      L_ARRAY_AMOUNT DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;

    BEGIN

      DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(L_INPUT_AMOUNT, '(^|,)', '\1x'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => L_ARRAY_AMOUNT);

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_COUNT);
      FOR I IN 1 .. L_COUNT
      LOOP

       INSERT INTO tbl(column1,column2,) values (SUBSTR(L_ARRAY_AMOUNT(I),2 ),:App_user ) ;
       COMMIT;
     END LOOP;
  END;
```

Comment: `COMMA_TO_TABLE()` is there to parse identifiers (names of objects. Initially created for replication purposes). Object names unless double-quoted cannot begin with a number or a special character (like `-` in this case), thus the error. You [can make it work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9005c55c6ccbd5187c12a9cffe5ffbc1) if each number in the list is doble-quoted `'"100", "-150","-250"'`, but it'd be better to implement your own method.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use this query:

```
select regexp_substr(L_INPUT_AMOUNT, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) result
  from test
  connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(L_INPUT_AMOUNT, '[^,]+')) + 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

`DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE` is not a general-purpose comma-separated values parsing routine. As noted in the comment for COMMA_TO_TABLE in the DBMS_UTILITY package header, COMMA_TO_TABLE calls `DBMS_UTILITY.NAME_TOKENIZE` to parse a "name", which is expected to be in the form a.b.c@dblink, with b, c, and dblink being optional. The '-' character is not valid in these strings and so it fails.